# Why does numpy have a corresponding function for many ndarray methods?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, methods, built-in

A few examples:

```
numpy.sum()
ndarray.sum()
numpy.amax()
ndarray.max()
numpy.dot()
ndarray.dot()
```

... and quite a few more. Is it to support some legacy code, or is there a better reason for that? And, do I choose only on the basis of how my code 'looks', or is one of the two ways better than the other?

I can imagine that one might want `numpy.dot()` to use `reduce` (e.g., `reduce(numpy.dot, A, B, C, D)`) but I don't think that would be as useful for something like `numpy.sum()`.

Comment: In most cases the function version ends up calling the method version (bound to the 1st argument).  But the function may have the longer `doc`. For the user it is mostly a matter of style.

Comment: See also this issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7452.  It seems the numpy developers would prefer to remove the method syntax, but can't due to the need to maintain backwards compatibility.  Personally I'd prefer it just be made consistent so that all functions could be called as methods rather than a select few.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As others have noted, the identically-named NumPy functions and array methods are often equivalent (they end up calling the same underlying code). One might be preferred over the other if it makes for easier reading.

However, in some instances the two behave different slightly differently. In particular, using the `ndarray` method sometimes emphasises the fact that the method is modifying the array in-place.

For example, [`np.resize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) returns a *new* array with the specified shape. On the other hand, [`ndarray.resize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html) changes the shape of the array in-place. The fill values used in each case are also different.

Similarly, `a.sort()` sorts the array `a` in-place, while `np.sort(a)` returns a sorted copy.

Comment: Mhhh... Not sure about `np.resize` vs. `ndarray.resize`, both seem to work in place. I just tried and if I do something like `C = np.reshape(A,(1,5))`, then `C[0,3] = 100` I find that also `A` has changed. (I'm on python 3.4, numpy 1.9.2.)

Comment: @Roberto:  Are you using `resize` or `reshape`? They're completely different functions - `ndarray.rehsape` and `np.reshape` both return new a new view of an array. `resize` can adjust the actual size of an array in memory, allocating more if needed.

Comment: Oh god it's one of those days. :) Yes, I don't know why I'm mixing up the two. Probably because they both begin with `re`.

Comment: No problem - I've mixed them up more than once myself :-)

Answer (score 6):

In most cases the method is the basic compiled version.  The function uses that method when available, but also has some sort of backup when the argument(s) is not an array.  It helps to look at the code and/or docs of the function or method.

For example if in `Ipython` I ask to look at the code for the sum method, I see that it is compiled code

```
In [711]: x.sum??
Type:        builtin_function_or_method
String form: <built-in method sum of numpy.ndarray object at 0xac1bce0>
...
Refer to `numpy.sum` for full documentation.
```

Do the same on `np.sum` I get many lines of documentation plus some Python code:

```
   if isinstance(a, _gentype):
        res = _sum_(a)
        if out is not None:
            out[...] = res
            return out
        return res
    elif type(a) is not mu.ndarray:
        try:
            sum = a.sum
        except AttributeError:
            return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
                                out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
        # NOTE: Dropping the keepdims parameters here...
        return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)
    else:
        return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
                            out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
```

If I call `np.sum(x)` where `x` is an array, it ends up calling `x.sum()`:

```
    sum = a.sum
    return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)
```

`np.amax` similar (but simpler).  Note that the `np.` form can handle a an object that isn't an array (that doesn't have the method), e.g. a list: `np.amax([1,2,3])`.

`np.dot` and `x.dot` both show as 'built-in' function, so we can't say anything about priority.  They probably both end up calling some underlying C function.

`np.reshape` is another that deligates if possible:

```
try:
    reshape = a.reshape
except AttributeError:
    return _wrapit(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
return reshape(newshape, order=order)
```

So `np.reshape(x,(2,3))` is identical in functionality to `x.reshape((2,3))`. But the `_wrapit` expression enables `np.reshape([1,2,3,4],(2,2))`.

`np.sort` returns a copy by doing an inplace sort on a copy:

```
a = asanyarray(a).copy()
a.sort(axis, kind, order)
return a
```

`x.resize` is built-in, while `np.resize` ends up doing a `np.concatenate` and `reshape`.

If your array is a subclass, like matrix or masked, it may have its own variant. The action of a matrix `.sum` is:

```
return N.ndarray.sum(self, axis, dtype, out, keepdims=True)._collapse(axis)
```

Comment: TIL about `??` in ipython

Comment: In `Ipython`, `?` means show me the doc, `??` show me the code.  It's a handy tool for code introspection.  And `.<tab>` lists possible completions.

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on Peter's comment for visibility:

> We could make it more consistent by removing methods from ndarray and sticking to just functions. But this is impossible because it would break everyone's existing code that uses methods.
>
> Or, we could move all functions to also be methods. But this is impossible because new users and packages are constantly defining new functions. Plus continuing to multiply these duplicate methods violates "there should be one obvious way to do it".
>
> If we could go back in time then I'd probably argue for not having these methods on ndarray at all, and using functions exclusively. ... So this all argues for using functions exclusively

[numpy issue: More consistency with array-methods #7452](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7452)