# When do you call an object.method versus a module.function in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

It seems that in Pandas you can do either of those:

```
age_is_null = pd.isnull(titanic_survival["age"])
age_is_null = titanic_survival["age"].isnull()
```

It seems that both exist: the function in Pandas module, and the method in the Dataframe class (in another module).

Coming from an Obj-C background, this is confusing. Why the need for both?

Comment: Relevant: [Why does numpy have a corresponding function for many ndarray methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120730/why-does-numpy-have-a-corresponding-function-for-many-ndarray-methods)

Answer (score 1):

`pd.isnull` works with inputs of different types (anything that is iterable) e.g

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pd.isnull(np.array([1, 2]))
array([False, False], dtype=bool)   
>>> pd.isnull([1, 2])
array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

whereas `df.isnull` is a member function bound to your DataFrame object. Hence you would use `pd.isnull` whenever creating a DataFrame first is to costly.

**Timings:**

```
In [30]: %timeit pd.isnull([1,2])
The slowest run took 8.93 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.19 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([1,2]).isnull()
The slowest run took 6.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 202 µs per loop
```