# ndarray .floor() and .ceil() methods missing?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm processing a numpy.matrix and I'm missing the round-up and down functions.
I.e. I can do:

```
data = [[1, -20],[-30, 2]]
np.matrix(data).mean(0).round().astype(int).tolist()[0]
Out[58]: [-14, -9]
```

Thus use `.round()`. But I cannot use `.floor()` or `.ceil()`.

They are also not mentioned in the [SciPy NumPy 1.14 reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/c-api.array.html).

Why are these (quite essential) functions missing?

edit:
 I've found that you can do `np.floor(np.matrix(data).mean(0)).astype(int).tolist()[0]`. But why the difference? Why is `.round()` a method and `.floor` not?

Comment: Of course they aren't missing. Have you tried [searching](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/search.html?q=ceil) for these functions?

Comment: Some things are functions rather than methods. Some are both.

Comment: Yes I've found that you can do `np.floor(np.matrix(data).mean(0)).astype(int).tolist()[0]`. But why the difference? Why is `.round()` a method and `.floor` not?

Comment: That's just by design, I guess? To be honest, I'd rather write `Array.floor().mean()` instead of `numpy.floor(Array).mean()` as well, but NumPy's developers don't want people to do this. Maybe they have their reasons.

Comment: @ForceBru what you write is not what I want., I want to `floor()` the *result* of the `mean()`. Not take the mean of the floor. flooring integers will not help... Anyhow: I don't understand they give you `round()` but not `floor()`. That's what my question is about

Comment: @JHBonarius, I understand, that was just an example. I don't think you'll get a better answer than "history + personal preference + slightly different behavior of methods & functions". A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120730/why-does-numpy-have-a-corresponding-function-for-many-ndarray-methods) has already been asked on SO, and there also was a discussion about this [here](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/ndarray-methods-vs-numpy-module-functions-td11701.html), but they didn't arrive at any conclusions, in my opinion.

Comment: Also, there's an empty entry called "Methods vs. Functions" in the [NumPy User's Guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.0/numpy-user-1.9.0.pdf), which means that people do understand that this design may cause confusion but don't really know how to explain that... or just don't care because you have the functionality, you have the speed, so a tiny, sort of, design flaw may be negligible.

Comment: OK, than my question will probably not be answered... too bad.

Answer (score 1):

As with most of these `why` questions we can only deduce likely reasons from patterns, and some knowledge of the history.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#floating-functions

`floor` and `ceil` are classed as `floating ufuncs`.  `rint` is also a `ufunc` that performs like `round`.  `ufuncs` have a standardized interface, including parameters like `out` and `where`.

`np.round` is in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py`.  `numeric` is one of original packages that was merged to form the current `numpy`.  It is alias for `np.round_` which ends up calling `np.around`, also in `fromnumeric`.  Note the available parameters include `out`, but also `decimals` (which is missing from `rint`).   And it delegates to the `.round` method.

One advantage to having a function is that you don't have to first convert the list into an array:

```
In [115]: data = [[1, -20],[-30, 2]]
In [119]: np.mean(data,0)
Out[119]: array([-14.5,  -9. ])
In [120]: np.mean(data,0).round()
Out[120]: array([-14.,  -9.])
In [121]: np.rint(np.mean(data,0))
Out[121]: array([-14.,  -9.])
```

using other parameters:

```
In [138]: np.mean(data,axis=0, keepdims=True,dtype=int)
Out[138]: array([[-14,  -9]])
```

Comment: Thanks. Then the question is: why is there a method `.round()`. does it add any value to have one? `np.round(np.mean(data,0))` <=> `data.mean(0).round()`. If the first works, I see no use for the second. If there is a specific case for the second, I don't get why `floor` and `ceil` are missing.