# "Direct" numpy functions on an array vs numpy array functions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question about the design of Python. I have realised that some functions are implemented directly on container classes (e.g. numpy arrays) while other function that act on these containers must be called from numpy itself. An example would be:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array([4,7,9,1])
m1 = np.mean(y)  # Ok
m2 = y.mean()  # Ok
print(m1 == m2)  # True

x = [2,3]
r1 = np.concatenate([x, y]) # Ok
r2 = y.concatenate(x)  # AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'concatenate'
print(r1 == r2)
```

Why can the mean be calculated directly from the array while the array as no method to concatenate another one to it? Is there a general rule which functions can be called directly on the array and which ones not? And if both is possible what is the pythonic way to do it?

Comment: Er.. because it's defined for [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and [`np.ndarray.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.mean.html) whilst there is no implementation for `np.ndarray.concatenate`. This has nothing to do with the language

Comment: Yes, but there must be a rational / strategy behind it?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120730/why-does-numpy-have-a-corresponding-function-for-many-ndarray-methods

Comment: @w-m I don't think this is a dupe, the OP is asking why only some methods have been implemented at top-level only, not what the differences are. Personally it doesn't make sense to implement this at that level, you have to contend with broadcasting, an axis arg that may or may not make sense depending on the array shapes etc.. Asking why is a difficult question to answer, unless it's documented or you can ask the devs who wrote the code

Comment: @w-m: your link brought me on the right track: the last (and zero rated) comment answers my question by linking to a github discussion: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7452 (njsmith's comment) . For me (coming from multiple different languages) this was just a bit confusing but it seems this is rather a design weakness that cant not be fixed anymore than a specific rational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overview of [NumPy history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy#History) gives an indication of why not everything is consistent: it has two predecessors that were developed independently. Backward compatibility requires the project to keep `array` methods like `max`. Ongoing development favors the function syntax `np.fun(array)`. I suppose one reason for the latter is that it allows `array_like` input (the term used throughout NumPy documentation): anything that NumPy can  turn into an `ndarray`.

Answer (score 2):

The question of why there are both methods and functions of the same name has been discussed and links provided.

But to focus on your two examples:

`mean` uses just one array.  Logically it can be an `ndarray` method.

`concatenate` takes a list of arrays, and doesn't give priority to any one of them.

There is a `np.append` function that looks superficially like the list `.append` method.  But it just passes the task on to `concatenate` with just a few modifications.  And it causes all kinds of newby errors - it isn't inplace, it ravels, and it is slow compared to the list method.

Or consider the large family of `ufunc`.  Those are functions, some take one array, others two.  They share a common `ufunc` functionality.

```
np.add(a,b)   <=> a+b   <=> a.__add__(b)
np.sin(a)    # no a.sin()
```

I suspect the choice to make `sin` a ufunc rather than a method has been influenced by common mathematical notation.

To me a big plus to the function approach is that it can be applied to a list or scalar. `np.sin(1)` works just as well as `np.sin([0,.5,1])` or `np.sin(np.arange(0,1,.5))`.

Yes, history goes a long way toward excusing the mix of functions of methods, but many of the choices are logical.